# Spyder IDE Version Operating System Requirements

Tags: operating-system, version, spyder, requirements

What are the Operating System Requirements for different versions of the Spyder IDE Windows Installer found at https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Our Windows installer works on Windows 10 (it probably works on Windows 8.1 too).

You can find the list of our system requirements in the section *Running Spyder* of our [FAQ](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#running-spyder)

Comment: Does that mean there are no versions of Spyder that run on Windows 7?  I saw that section which mentions windows 8.1, but I thought that might be for the most recent Spyder Windows installer.  I thought there might be different system requirements for different versions of Spyder.  I'd like to use Spyder on a computer running Windows 7.  Also the computer is offline.

Comment: You need to use Anaconda to get Spyder working on Windows 7. But for our installer you need Windows 10 preferably (we haven't tested on Windows 8.1, but it should work too).

Comment: Also, please remember that official support for Windows 7 ended at beginning of this year.

Comment: Are there specific versions of Spyder that need to be used for Windows 7?  According to `https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/` for Windows 7 "Use the command line or graphical installers for Anaconda versions 2019.10 and earlier".  Should all Anaconda versions 2019.10 and earlier provide Spyder which works in Windows 7 too?  I would assume so, but I would rather ask to be confident.  Thanks for you responses!  They are very helpful and appreciated. :)

Comment: No, there are not specific versions of Spyder for Windows 7. Also, any Anaconda version should support Windows 7 (as far as I know). And glad my responses have been helpful to you.